# Does Tomcat have default cipher suite list

Tags: security, ssl, tomcat, tomcat8

I have configured my Tomcat 8.5 cipher suites as below

```xml
    <Connector
      ....
      sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1.2" 
      ciphers="
            TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,
            TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
            TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,
            TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA"
    ... />
```

While testing the site with [www.ssllabs.com](https://www.ssllab.com) I find strange result in  Server Supported Cipher Suites section. The list is as below :

```
    TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384  ....   OK
    TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384  ....   WEAK
    TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA     ....   WEAK
    TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256  ....   OK
    TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256  ....   WEAK
    TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA     ....   WEAK
```

Where are the `TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384` and `TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256` come from, I have not configure them in ‍`server.xml` ?!

Is it any default list of cipher suites in tomcat ?!

Comment: Unless you configure it otherwise it has the same defaults as the JRE it is running under.

Comment: Thanks, I find the list of default enabled cypher suites at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html#SupportedCipherSuites.  I just wonder why the ssllab shows just two protocols while the jre supported cypher suites are much more than that.

Comment: It doesn't show two enabled protocols. It shows six, of which four are weak.

Comment: @user207421 These are ciphers showing as weak, not *protocols*. The protocol for all of those ciphers is TLSv1.2.

Comment: When you specify `ciphers`, no additional ciphers should be available. Are you sure that your configuration is actually being used?

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz I have rechecked the `server.xml`and it has 4 ciphers. The tomcat version is 8.5.41. The Jdk is 1.8.0_131. There is a BigIp device in between tomcat and clients, is it possible that this device add supports for these ciphers.

Comment: Does your BigIP terminate TLS? If so, the ciphers you list in Tomcat aren't what affects what clients can negotiate with your site. You'll have to adjust your BigIP configuration.

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz I will check that. I appreciate if you could post an answer so I can mark it as correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you specify `ciphers`, no additional ciphers will be made available, regardless of the capabilities of the cryptographic provider being used (e.g. JSSE, OpenSSL, etc.).

If you are seeing a different set of cipher suites being negotiated, I would check two things:

1. Your configuration is actually being used. Try adding a syntactic error to your XML configuration file to see if Tomcat still starts. Tomcat should refuse to start if the file is not well-formed, confirming that you are in fact changing the right configuration file.
2. If you are not directly connecting to Tomcat, you may be negotiating your TLS handshake with another network component such as a reverse proxy which is terminating TLS. If that's the case, the configuration of Tomcat is not relevant; the client is really talking to the reverse proxy and not to Tomcat, so the list of ciphers will be different as far as the client can tell. You will need to reconfigure the reverse proxy in this situation. The cipher suites list in Tomcat is still important, as you want to be using a secure cipher suite even "inside" your own network.